# Как залить правый (розовый блок) до края экрана через :after?

Tags: html, css, frontend

На экране должны быть два блока `70%/30%`, в контейнере `1170px`. Как залить правый блок до края экрана через псевдоэлемент `:after`?

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #6699ff;
    }
    *, ::after, ::before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    h2 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: roboto;
      margin: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .container {
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      max-width: 1170px;
    }
    .content {
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      margin: 20px;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .left {
      width: 70%;
    }
    .right {
      position: relative;
      width: 30%;
      background: #d39;
    }
    
    /* ????????????????? */
    .right:before {
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #d39;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100vh;
      content: "";
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>left<br> content<br> contained<br> here<h2>
        </div>
      </div>
         
      <div class="right">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>right<br> content<br> contained<br> here<h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не мое дело конечно, но к чему псевдо-элементы? Просто любопытно...

Comment: Другого решения для данной задачи, не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Задать псевдоэлементу нужный фон, ширину заведомо большую правого отступа `.container`, отпозиционировать его(псевдоэлемент) справа от родителя, запретить body прокрутку по горизонтали.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #6699ff;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1170px;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
}
.left {
  width: 70%;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  background: #d39;
}

/* ????????????????? */
.right:before {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d39;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
}

.right:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  background-color:#d39;
}
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>left<br> content<br> contained<br> here</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
     
  <div class="right">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>right<br> content<br> contained<br> here</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! вот это я искал :) - overflow-x:hidden;